# How to select the first preceding-sibling which has a particular node as child?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have been trying to write a XPath statement which will select the first preceding-sibling of a node. That sibling should have a particular node as its child.

For example:

```
<a>
    <c></c>
    ....
    <b></b>
</a>

<a></a>
....
....
<a></a>

<a>
   <b> start </b>
</a>
```

In the above XML, if my context is at the node `a` which has `start` text inside its child `b`. How can I select the preceding node `a` whose child is `b`?

I tried `preceding-sibling::*[b][1]` but it only selects the node `a` if `b` is its first child. I also tried `preceding-sibling::*[1][b]` but it only checks the first preceding `a` node and if it doesn't contains `b`, the test fails.

**Note:** I am using XSLT 1.0

Can anyone suggest me a solution?

Thnx in advance!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe that:

```
preceding-sibling::*[b][1]
```

or preferably:

```
preceding-sibling::a[b][1]
```

should work just fine.

> I tried preceding-sibling::*[b][1] but it only selects the node a if b
>   is its first child.

I don't think that is so.

Comment: Just for the sake if it, the expression that *"selects the node `a` only if `b` is its first child"* is `preceding-sibling::a[*[1][self::b]]`.

Answer (score 7):

Like this. (*"The first preceding sibling who has a `<b>` child"*):

```
preceding-sibling::a[b][1]
```

or this (*"The first preceding sibling but only if it has a `<b>` child"*):

```
preceding-sibling::a[1][b]
```

---

Multiple predicates must be true one after another. Therefore, this:

```
preceding-sibling::a[b and position() = 1]
```

is equivalent to the second expression, but not to the first.

Comment: It seems to work just as well without the parentheses.

Comment: No, I don't think so. I didn't use the OP's example.

Answer (score 1):

With this input:

```
<root>
    <a>
        <c></c>
        <b>SUCCESS</b>
    </a>
    <a>FAIL</a>
    <a>FAIL</a>
    <a>
        <b> start </b>
    </a>
</root>
```

and this stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="a[b[.=' start ']]">
        <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="preceding-sibling::a[b]"/>
        </xsl:copy>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

it outputs

```
<root>
   <a>
      <c/>
      <b>SUCCESS</b>
   </a>
   <a>FAIL</a>
   <a>FAIL</a>
   <a>SUCCESS</a>
</root>
```

Comment: if there are multiple instances of node `a` with child `b`, change `preceding-sibling::a[b]` to `preceding-sibling::a[b][1]`