# XSL template match only if a preceding sibling's child is not a certain node

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, ms-word, openxml

I have a particular question a lot like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21695830/how-to-select-the-first-preceding-sibling-which-has-a-particular-node-as-child), but in my case I want to only have a match if any of the preceding sibling's child does not contain a certain node.

In my case I have this XML from a Word document:

```
<w:r>
    <w:drawing>

    </w:drawing>
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidR="00AE7312">
    <w:rPr>
        <w:i/>
        <w:iCs/>
        <w:w w:val="100"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>Some italic text</w:t>
</w:r>
```

I want to avoid `w:r's` that contain both `w:i` and `w:drawing`.
The xsl I have tried so far are variations of this:

```
  <xsl:template match="w:r[./w:rPr/w:i][not(preceding-sibling::*[w:drawing][1])]">
    <i><xsl:value-of select="."/></i>
  </xsl:template>
```

and this

```
  <xsl:template match="w:r[./w:rPr/w:i] and not(preceding-sibling::w:r[w:drawing][1])]">
    <i><xsl:value-of select="."/></i>
  </xsl:template>
```

So far, I am still getting a template match when I don't want one.

If anyone is wondering what I am doing, I am converting word files to dita/XML files. In this instance, I am trying to add `<i>` tags to italic text. However, there are instances in my word documents where an image is inside a table along with some italic text and I need to avoid matching this situation to preserve the images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
w:r[./w:rPr/w:i][not(preceding-sibling::*[w:drawing][1])]
```

to

```
w:r[w:rPr/w:i][preceding-sibling::w:r[1][not(w:drawing)]]
```

in order to match those `w:r` with an italic property that are not immediately preceding by a `w:r` sibling with a `w:drawing` child.

### Complete Example

```
<w:p xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
  <w:r>
    <w:drawing/>
  </w:r>
  <w:r w:rsidR="00AE7312">
    <w:rPr>
      <w:i/>
      <w:iCs/>
      <w:w w:val="100"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>Some italic text 1</w:t>
  </w:r>
  <w:r w:rsidR="00AE7312">
    <w:rPr>
      <w:i/>
      <w:iCs/>
      <w:w w:val="100"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>Some italic text 2</w:t>
  </w:r>
</w:p>
```

### XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
           xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main"
                exclude-result-prefixes="w">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="w:r[w:rPr/w:i][preceding-sibling::w:r[1][not(w:drawing)]]">
    <i><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/></i>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="w:p">
    <p><xsl:apply-templates/></p>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### XML Out

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p>
   <i>Some italic text 2</i>
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks kjhughes. Please be patient for me to check the code, as I am not going to be around my laptop for the rest of the evening. I'll have to wait till the morning to try this out.

Comment: I ended up using `w:r[./w:rPr/w:i][not(w:drawing)]` because I found out that some preceding siblings of my images were not `w:r` with `w:drawing` as a child, making a match where I didn't want a match. With the way I worded this question though, your answer is correct, so I marked it as the correct answer. Thank you.